# Without foreign key in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

i want to add in my migration field parent_id, but it isn't FK, how i can say it to rails? Thanks, i read about this, but forgot and now can't find it..

Comment: maybe :references => nil

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can just add it in the same way as any other field:

for example

```
rails g migration add_parent_id_to_foo parent_id:string
```

or

```
class AddParentIdToFoo < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    add_column :foos, :parent_id, :string (or integer or whatever)
  end

  def self.down
    remove_column :foos, :parent_id
  end
end
```